# SwiftUI - Passing a variable up through View Hierarchy and back down again?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have 3 views: 1) `ContentView`, which has a `TabView` leading to 2) `NestedView`, which has a popup view that darkens the screen behind it called 3) `SelectView`

Here is the necessary code for `ContentView`.  I have a `TabView` leading to `NestedView` and a condition to darken and blur the background when `darken` is true.

```
 TabView (selection: $selection){
                
                NestedView()
                    .tabItem {
                        selection == 0 ? Image(systemName: "house.fill") : Image(systemName: "house")
                    }
                    .tag(0)   
            }   
            if darken {
                ZStack {
                    ZStack {
                        Rectangle()
                            .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.black).opacity(0.75)
                    }.background(Blur(style: .systemChromeMaterial).opacity(0.85)
                        .ignoresSafeArea(.all))
                    SelectView(darken: $darken)
                }
```

I want to pass in data to the SelectView constructor, but I'm not sure how to get the data there.

Here is the code for `NestedView`

```
    @State var dataArray: [ItemDataModel]
    @Binding var darken: Bool

Button(action: {
                darken = true
            }) {
```

I need dataArray to be sent through the `SelectView` constructor in `ContentView`.

In `SelectView` I have a Binding variable for darken, and I know I need another for the received data, but I'm not sure whether it needs to be @State or @Binding or something entirely different.

```
@Binding var darken: Bool
@________ var dataArray: [ItemDataModel]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NestedView` should not have a `@State var dataArray: [ItemDataModel]`.

`NestedView` and `SelectView` should both have a `@Binding var dataArray: [ItemDataModel]`.

You should move `@State var dataArray: [ItemDataModel]` up into `ContentView` so it can pass `$dataArray` down to both `NestedView` and `SelectView`.

Comment: Thanks! I've now run into another issue, which is that the @State in ContentView needs a default parameter, but there really isn't a "default".  Does it mattter what I put here since it should be getting changed anyway with the data that gets passed through?

Comment: I assume you load the initial value in a `.onAppear` or `.task` in `NestedView`, so initializing it to an empty array in `ContentView` is probably fine.